# GAIDictionaryBuilder fails for NSNumber values

Tags: ios, google-analytics, nsmutabledictionary, nsnumber

I am trying to send commerce transaction data to google analytics on iOS with V3 SDK. I am building the data dictionary using GAIDictionaryBuilder class provided by Google (which is not open source unfortunately). For both createTransactionWithId and createItemWithTransactionId calls, my NSNumber values (revenue, price, etc.) are failing to be added to dictionary data properly. Here is the sample code:

```
NSMutableDictionary* test = [[GAIDictionaryBuilder createTransactionWithId:(NSString *)transactionId
                                                                  affiliation:(NSString *)affiliation
                                                                      revenue:(NSNumber *)revenue
                                                                          tax:(NSNumber *)tax
                                                                     shipping:(NSNumber *)shipping
                                                                 currencyCode:(NSString *)currencyCode] build];
    NSLog(@"revenue: %@", revenue);
    NSLog(@"TR data: %@", test);

    // if I explicitly set the value, IT WORKS!!!!
    [test setObject:revenue forKey:@"&tr"];
    NSLog(@"TR data FIXED??: %@", test);
```

In the output, I see revenue correctly, then when logging test dictionary I see the following line corresponding to revenue data:

```
"&tr" = "<null>";
```

Then, for the manual fix attempt, I see

```
"&tr" = "15.25";
```

as expected.

Here are some clues:

- I use the same code in a different project compiled in a different OSX machine without any issues like this.
- The transactions are in TRY (Turkish Lira), I suspect Google is trying to fix the separator (',' in Turkish vs '.' everywhere else), but as said above, the other app is also using TRY.

So the question is, why `"<null>"`, why and how does it fail to convert a proper NSNumber to this bizarre value?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I fixed the issue by working around it. I assigned the NSNumber to a new one (by getting its floatValue) and it seemed to fix the null values.

By the way, google analytics library version 3.07 readme mentions a similar issue as fixed however neither 3.03 nor 3.07 actually fixed my problem.